# How To Set The Container Height Of These Objects With Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

My app has database objects for grid layouts.  Each layout has blocks with different sizes and positions and each layout is kept in an array like this:

```
var array = [{ row:1, col: 1, size: 2 },{ row:1, col: 2, size 1 },{ row:1, col: 3, size: 2 },{ row:2, col: 1, size:1 },{ row:2, col: 2, size:1 },{ row:2, col: 3, size:2 }]
```

To display a layout on the website, I iterate through the array and set the position of each block with absolute positioning.

The problem is that I need to set the height of the element that contains these blocks, but I can't seem to do it with CSS.  How Can I do this in Javascript?

Hints:

- The grid's columns are fixed, but the row height is not.
- size: 1 = 1 row tall  and  size: 2 = 2 rows tall

Comment: can you include the output html and css?

Comment: We need more information to accurately help you out. Could you include the HTML/CSS in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something? If we can see what you see, we can give suggestions on how to approach the issue.